# Как принудительно задать в Yii2 gridview для пустого типа datetime текстовую метку

Tags: yii2, datetime, gridview

На данный момент в бд хранится `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Естественно в gridview отображается некорректно. Мне необходимо при выводе чтобы отображалось "не задано". Вот кусок кода:

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return ['class' => OfferStatus::find()->select(['class', 'id'])->andWhere(['id' => $model['offer_status']])->column()];
    },
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'date_accept',
            'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.y H:m'],
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: А как выводите gridview?

Comment: Добавил часть кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте кастомную колонку для поля с датой, а для даты можно использовать объект [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'date_accept',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            $date = new \DateTime($model->date_accept);

            if ($date->getTimestamp() < 0) {
                return 'Не задано';
            }

            return $date->format('d.m.y H:m');
        }
    ],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
]
```

Comment: Вариант тоже хороший. Правда придется сортировку подгонять

Comment: @Bumerang37 как это влияет на сортировку?

Comment: создавал через crud генератор. Если через `label` то название столбца просто текст, в моем случае по нажатии на столбец сортирует по возрастанию/убыванию

Comment: @Bumerang37 тогда добавьте 'attribute' => 'date_accept' вместо 'label' => 'Date accept' чтобы фильтр работал

Comment: точно, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно где-то ошибся, но в целом решение подобно следующему:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return ['class' => OfferStatus::find()->select(['class', 'id'])->andWhere(['id' => $model['offer_status']])->column()];
    },
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'date_accept',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                    switch ($data->date_accept) {
                        case '0000-00-00 00:00:00':
                            return 'не задано';
                            break;

                        default:
                            return $data->date_accept;
                            break;
                    }
                },
            'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.y H:m'],
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Ваш вариант хорошо подходит, только `format` принимать не хочет

Comment: Отформатируйте в switch операторе